# Is wrapping Unity's C# Monobehavior efficient?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Should I wrap most of my (150+) C# monobehaviors with another abstract class that I control, and add functions to it? Or is this hilariously inefficient, if only, say, 60% of the monobehaviors will use the functions in my special wrapper class? The alternative is adding an onDestroy and various other functions to every class. What are the advantages to having these functions in by composition, rather than just inheriting them automatically everywhere?

I work with DoTween (a tweening library) and MEC (instead of coroutines), and I run every coroutine and tween with a tag, or on a gameobject. Whenever I do these things, I register the tag or gameobject with a class that tracks them for me. I do this so I can pause the game at any time without messing with Time.timeScale, and get a "real" pause. The downside to using MEC is that when you kill a gameobject, it does not automatically stop your coroutine -- I'd like to do this manually in my wrapper class. This is why I am wondering whether I should do this.

Comment: Do you mean creating a class `M` that extends MonoBehaviour and making `M` implement Update, Start, etc, and then having all of your classes extend `M`? Don't do that.

Comment: Monobehaviors are expensive. We usually only have one to get an update and run coroutines on.

Comment: @Draco18s I mean creating a class M that has some bonus functions on it, like RemoveAllTagsRelatedToClassMFromTaggingSystem(). I wouldn't try to override update.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Is it possible to have a class appear in the inspector and not be a monobehaviour? Is that what ScriptableObjects are for? Seems like if I couldn't use the inspector, I'd be causing myself a lot of trouble.

I don't run any update functions, and there's only one Start function in my whole codebase. Do you think those monobehaviors are still dragging me down?

Comment: As far as I know the problem is with the number of calls to Update function, not with the number of MonoBehaviours. You can read more here: https://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/12/23/1k-update-calls/  (section `It doesn’t work with intellisense` and below) good luck

Answer (score 2):

It actually depends of your game, but short answer is:
yes, MonoBehaviours have a lot of overhead, and this can be really noticeable if you get a lot of them in your scene, the actual problem of MonoBehaviour is the magic methods (update, start, awake, etc)

This [article](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/12/23/1k-update-calls/) and this [one](https://blog.theknightsofunity.com/monobehavior-calls-optimization/) shows that removing all of your behaviour and having a single one that is managing all of the wrapped behaviour may increase performance by up to 11 times,

you can also find other [references](https://answers.unity.com/questions/966269/what-exactly-is-going-on-when-i-implement-update-a.html) showing exactly what happen behind the scenes when implementing the magic methods (short answer, not reflection)